# Inject serviceImplementation in Guice module

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I am noob to Guice, trying to get a hang on the dependency injection provided by Guice. I want to inject a interface implementation as apart of Cache. Below code snippet is what I have currently implemented:

```
class CacheModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        bind(DBService.class).to(DBServiceImpl.class);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @com.google.inject.name.Named("CacheName")
    public LoadingCache<String, Object> getCache() {
        DBService dbservice = new DBServiceImpl();
        LoadingCache<String, Object> result = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .maximumSize(100).expireAfterAccess(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build(new CacheLoader<String, Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public String load(String key) throws Exception {
                        return dbservice.getData(1);
                    }
                });

        return result;
    }
}
```

Is this the current way to initialize `DBService dbservice = new DBServiceImpl();` so that the object `dbservice` can be used in the `load()` method of the cache? It seems to be like a cyclic loop to be attempting to inject the seviceImpl in the Module

In future, I would like to make it easy so that I can create `dbService` can refer to a different object type implementing `DBService`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use [injections](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections) to inject `DBService` impl to your custom `CacheProvider` class, like

```
class CacheModule extends AbstractModule {

  @Override
  public void configure() {
      bind(DBService.class).to(DBServiceImpl.class);
  }
}

class CacheProvider {

  private DBservice dbservice;

  @Inject
  CacheProvider(DBservice dbservice) {
    this.dbservice = dbservice;
  } 

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  @com.google.inject.name.Named("CacheName")
  public LoadingCache<String, Object> getCache() {
      LoadingCache<String, Object> result = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
              .maximumSize(100).expireAfterAccess(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
              .build(new CacheLoader<String, Object>() {
                  @Override
                  public String load(String key) throws Exception {
                      return dbservice.getData(1);
                  }
              });

      return result;
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /*
     * Guice.createInjector() takes your Modules, and returns a new Injector
     * instance. Most applications will call this method exactly once, in their
     * main() method.
     */
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new CacheModule());

    /*
     * Now that we've got the injector, we can build objects.
     */
    CacheProvider cacheProvider = injector.getInstance(CacheProvider.class);
    cacheProvider.getCache();
    ...
}
```

Now you can use `CacheProvider` to get cache with `DBService` impl that you bind in `main` method.

Comment: I get a null pointer exception when I opt for the above suggested approach..I am injecting the module as `Injector injector = createInjector(
            new CacheModule()
        );` If using the above approach, I believe I need to initialize DBService elsewhere?

Comment: I edited my answer, I have added `@Inject` on constructor, can you check if it works

Comment: That does not work either... Same result: Null pointer exception

Comment: I've extract `getCache` to separate method, now you can bind `DBService` impl that you want.